# Debian Linux Server not Starting

Tags: debian, startup

My computer is running Debian Linux and is having a problem starting up.  After I select the OS from the GRUB bootloader, I see messages for the drivers being loaded then I get a completely pixelated screen and getting stuck there.  I have not installed any new hardware. What could be causing this?

EDITED: Here is a video of the boot process: http://youtu.be/NutfywloGO0

EDITED: Here is a screenshot of the pixelated screen.  Could it be that the resolution is out of limits?  How could I edit that if that is the case.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried selecting the rescue option off the boot menu?

Comment: @Zoredache Yes, it is also ending up in a pixelated screen.  In fact I was not able to get the server to restart when selecting recovery mode.

Comment: Note: The server is within a hosting company's environment and I am using a KVM client to connect to it remotely.

Comment: this is a headless server yes, x is not installed correct? it's fubar. get the hardrive(s) put into another machine.

Comment: Can you please add a picture of the "pixelated screen"?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't accidentically install X or something? maybe it got pulled in as a dependency from a package you previously added?

Comment: @Matt I have added a screenshot and a video to the original post.

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici I have added a screenshot and a video to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Can the server boot in single user mode?
If yes, the problem is in a daemon contained in /etc/rc2.d/.
If no, the problem is before in boot process.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Ctrl+Alt+F2 or F3" , you should see the text console of the boot process. The last started process or status should lead you to the correct solution.

Comment: I am seeing the text console of the boot process without pressing any key.  But when the boot process is over, I am getting the pixelated screen.

Comment: What is the last process its completed ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a graphic card problem, you may activate serial console and access to your server from your pc using a serial cable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hardware or driver problem.

If you expect to be a driver problem, try to boot with a LiveCD. If it is working try to configure the Debian kernel to use VGA or try `noapic`, `acpi=off` etc. Try to boot with a different kernel.

If you expect to be a hardware problem, then check the following components in this order:

- VGA card - by replacing it with a good one
- memory - run a memory test from the BIOS of the server, run a memory test suite like `memtest86+`
- power supply - replace with a good one
- motherboard - replace with a good one
- CPU - run a CPU test from a LiveCD

Switching cards around could fix the problem if you have a IRQ sharing an a broken driver.

EDIT:

From the video I can see that you are starting X. You do not need this on a server. Try to disable it. Change in the /etc/inittab the initdefault line from 5 to 2:

```
id:2:initdefault
```

Comment: Did you see the video I posted?

Comment: Can you add `vga=ask` as a boot parameter? This will ask for videomode. Try each one and see which is workin and then replace `vga=ask` with `vga=###` where ### is the mode that works.

Comment: Also remove any splash option in grub

Comment: vga=ask is not working.  I am getting a message saying that the legacy 'ask' parameter is no longer supported.  For disabling X, is there any text editor in GRUB?  The shell provided by GRUB is very limited.

Comment: You have to boot in single user mode to be able to edit `/etc/inittab`, or to boot from a CD

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once, when the grub splash file was corrupted or not available. Could you check that? Please also post you full grub config and partition layout.